# eliminate the extension html from a web page name

Tags: url, web

my first page in my website called index.html
when I put in the address bar :
 `http://websit/index.html` it works

**but**

now my boss asked me that he wants the name just  `http://websit/index`

how can I do that?

Comment: maybe duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245032/url-rewrite-remove-html

Answer (score 0):

Standard web server behavior is to just load the "index.html" file as the root file of a path call.  Meaning this:

```
http://websit/
```

Is the same as this:

```
http://websit/index.html
```

Doing something like this (below) will only cause more problems since it would seem that index is a path instead of a file:

```
http://websit/index
```

So any if you want to clean things up just make any reference to `http://websit/index.html` just `http://websit/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, then, you need to check if Mod Rewrite is enabled, and then, read articles about .htaccess and mod rewrite.

The solution:
Create a file with this name exactly .htaccess on root directory (where the index.html) is there. Then, copy this code (paste it inside the .htaccess file) and test it again using website/index without .html

```
#comments
RewriteEngine On

#base directory for this file, if its root, then its one /, if its test then its /test
RewriteBase /

#if the URL for the resource that requested is not exist as file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#if the URL for the resource not exist as directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

#then it anything types after the website/() redirect it to ().html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#the ^ and $ used for matching whole string (from beginning to end)
#the () used for grouping matching strings
#the . used for matching any character
#the $1 represents the match group, for our example we used one () then its $1
```

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html