# How to show HTML website URLs like wordpress

Tags: url, pretty-urls

I'm creating a website for my personal needs. I have different pages like `index.html`, `about.html`, `contact.html` etc... 
The default way of showing them is `mysite.com/index.html` or `mysite.com/contact.html`

But is there any way to hide the extension part `.html` and just to show the url main texts like `mysite.com/about/` or `mysite.com/contact/` ??

Please advice me.

Comment: Well `mysite.com/about/` is generally the same as `mysite.com/about/index.html` (depending on server settings). For a more dynamic approach you would use URL Rewriting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: @deceze, thanks for noticing me this thread too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a URL rewrite engine, edit (or create) the .htaccess like that:

```
# Remove .html from url
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

For more details: [Remove .html from URLs with a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245032/url-rewrite-remove-html)

Comment: Adding to this answer, your web server has to support url rewriting. For Apache (one of the most used) you have to install a module called mod_rewrite. For other web servers, look at the docs if they support it.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to show  your page with mysite.com/about/

1. You need to replace all file name to **index.html**
2. Eg : **about.html** to **index.html**
3. Add index.html to their respective pages, like

**Before:**

```
www/
|
|-about/about.html
|
|-contact/contact.html
|
|-etc/etc.html
```

**After :**

```
www/
|
|-about/index.html
|
|-contact/index.html
|
|-etc/index.html
```

Now when you hit the URL **www.yourSite.com/about** that page will be shown. (without *about.html* part)

Comment: -1. Sorry, that's a really poor suggestion.

Comment: he haven't mentioned any server side URL rewriting for this, so basic OP is this I believe!

Comment: It's irrelevant if the OP mentioned it or not. This is a bad solution.

Comment: OP didn't mentioned it because maybe he didn't know. Your intentions were good, but far from optimal

Comment: What is this OP anyway?? OutPut?

Comment: @user1012181 OP == Original Post/Poster